# Access base class variable from metaclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaprogramming

I am trying to read base class variable from metaclass to override class variable using this code:

```
class TypeBaseMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, namespace, **kwds):
        for base in bases:
            namespace['__validators__'] = base['__validators__'] + namespace['__validators__']

        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, namespace, **kwds)

class TypeBase(metaclass=TypeBaseMeta):
    __validators__ = ('presence')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def validate_presence(self, flag):
        if self.data:
            return True

class String(TypeBase):
    __validators__ = ('length')

    def validate_length(self, range):
        if len(self.data) in range(*range):
            return True
```

but I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "types.py", line 18, in <module>
    class String(TypeBase):
  File "types.py", line 4, in __new__
    namespace['__validators__'] = base['__validators__'] + namespace['__validators__']
TypeError: 'TypeBaseMeta' object is not subscriptable
```

---

I know that subscriptable object must have `__getitem__()` and behave like dictionaries and list but I have no idea what is causing this error.

Comment: Your validators are strings, not tuples of strings. A single element tuple is specified as `(item,)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__validators__` is an attribute of the superclass, not a dict item, so it should be accessed with `base.__validators__`.  (That is, change `base['__validators__']` to `base.__validators__`.  Don't change `namespace['__validators__']`.)

The reason you access the attribute of the *current* class with `namespace['__validators__']` is because that class doesn't exist yet (it is being created by the metaclass).  Right now all you have is a dict of its attributes.  But the *superclass* (`base`) was already created, and is a real class whose attributes are accessed in the normal way, with `.`.

As Dunes points out in a comment, your code has another problem, which is that you should be writing `('presence',)` and `('length',)` for your validators, to create tuples.  Otherwise they are just strings, and the subclass's `__validators__` will be set to the single string `'presencelength'`.

Comment: I got `KeyError: '__validators__'` when I change `namespace['__validators__']` to `base.__validators__`.

Comment: @RalphGutkowski: Don't change `namespace['__validators__']`.  Change `base['__validators__']`.  (I added a clarification in my answer.)

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I made a mistake. I changed `base['__validators__']` but still got same error. Full line: `namespace['__validators__'] = base.__validators__ + namespace['__validators__']`

Comment: @RalphGutkowski: I can't reproduce that.  When I run your code with my suggested change, it works with no errors.  See [this ideone example](http://ideone.com/daxgpg).

Comment: My bad. At the end of my file I've got class that extend from TypeBase  that doesn't have `__validators__` variable. Thank you for help. I would give you another +1 for perfect explanation you wrote!

Answer (score 2):

The `__validators__` variable in the superclasses is not acessible as if it were a dictionary - you have to fecth it from it's `__dict__` attribute, or use `getattr`.

```
- namespace['__validators__'] = base['__validators__'] + namespace['__validators__']
+  namespace['__validators__'] = base.__dict__.get('__validators__', ()) + namespace['__validators__']
```